# How to mapping data of gridview to my Class

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-window

In wpf application I can map data of gridview to my Class eg:

```
class MyClass{
    string field1;
    string field2;
}
```

when I save grid data to Database, I can:

```
for (MyClass m in radGridView1.Items){
// doing
}
```

How can I do like this in telerik winform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out solution:

the first one we must set `DataSource` for `gridview`: after that we can use like:

```
foreach (var i in (List<MyClass >)radGridView1.DataSource)
{ 
}
```